# How to force caching to work for View with filter by date offset?

Tags: views, caching

Faced with a strange situation: if a View uses filter "Post date" (or similar) with an offset (eg, "> = -1 month"), this View won't cache.

Example: I create a simple View with Block display.

- Field: "Content: Title"
- Caching: "Time-based | 1 hour/1 hour"
- Block caching: "Cache once for everything (global)"

Of course, global setting "Cache blocks" is on.

If I place this block on a page, it is cached properly.

I want to filter nodes for a certain period of time. I add filter with an offset from the current time: "Content: Post date (>= -1 month)". And this block will no longer be cached! Every time I load a page with this block, there is a new call to the database ("SELECT node.title AS node_title ..."). In addition, the table "cache_views_data" is filling with multiple records like "my_view:block_1:results:1a2s3d4d" and "my_view:block_1:output:m0n9b8v7".

How could I force caching of this block to work?

Comment: Remind me, can you set granularity on post date filter?

Comment: No. Granularity is on sort only.

Comment: Too bad. With granularity larger than one hour it should work. I suspect cache is auto-off due to time-based filter. How far outside Views and maybe even Drupal are you willing to go for solution? Because I don't know how to fix views (and if that's what you want, maybe you should file a bugreport), but I believe I know ways around it.

Comment: I'd like to stay inside Drupal, if it is possible. :)

Comment: So I wish you good luck and go to get my sleep. Now I don't have anything like answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a particular workaround [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1469188).

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal caching system, there's an option to cache pages/blocks for anonymous users only, maybe it's the same thing for **Views**. Check if it works with a not logged in user.